# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(byte[])'

Tags: java, pdfbox, nosuchmethoderror

My Project previously used the pdfbox 1.7 dependency. then I switched to 2.0.25 and I am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(byte[])'
```

Checking the class path and the jar of the lib it is possible to verify that the class has the method, however the error continues.

Below is a code snippet where I try to read the pages of a pdf.

```
public static void analyseImageEntirePagePdfAto(byte[] sourcePdf) throws Throwable{
        PDDocument docAto = PDDocument.load(sourcePdf);
        int p = 0;
        PDPageTree pageTree = docAto.getPages();
        for (PDPage pagina : pageTree){
            p++;
            PDFTextStripper reader = new PDFTextStripper();
            reader.setStartPage(p);
            reader.setEndPage(p);
            String pageText = reader.getText(docAto);
            if (pageText != "" && pageText != null){
                System.out.println("Página " + String.valueOf(p) + " contém o texto: " + pageText.substring(0,20) + "...");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Página não contém o texto.");
            }
            PDResources pdResources = pagina.getResources();
            int qtdImg = 0;
            for (COSName c : pdResources.getXObjectNames()){
                PDXObject o = pdResources.getXObject(c);
                if (o instanceof PDImageXObject){
                    qtdImg++;
                    PDImageXObject i = (PDImageXObject) o;
                    System.out.println("  Imagem " + String.valueOf(qtdImg) + " possui medidas: h - " + String.valueOf(i.getHeight()) + " w - " + String.valueOf(i.getHeight()));                   
                }
            }           
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you update all neeed dependencies and rebuilt the deployment?

Comment: Yes. All project dependencies were downloaded and I rebuilt the project.

Comment: Something is Expecting another version of the library with that method in it.  Can the original developer have a look at the code?

Comment: Are you sure the deployment is correct?

Comment: I'm using eclipse + tomcat 8. I realized now that when I published the updated code in tomcat, I was going to lib pdfbox 1.7.0.

Comment: Are you using eclipse? Anyway, mention the IDE in  the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. I temporarily solved my problem by manually removing the old libs, in the directory C:\TOMCAT\apache-tomcat-8.0.32\wtpwebapps\mp-diariooficial\WEB-INF\lib